How do I set attributes (particularly color) of a GtkTextView in GTK4 in C?
Thanks in advance for the help.
Here's the situation:

I would like to set up an interaction that changes the background color of a GtkTextView under certain circumstances, e.g. if it's focused.
I have found methods such as gtk_text_set_attributes and gtk_label_set_attributes.
However, I can't find an equivalent for GtkTextView.

Thoughts on why such an equivalent doesn't exist, and how I might build a workaround?
Thank you!

I think the best method is to use CSS here. There are more questions and answers on this.
One example is available here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78729982/22768315
It would then only have to be reloaded and applied to the intended event the provider.
Here is a simple example of how it could go.
 
#include"textwiew-css.h"

G_GNUC_BEGIN_IGNORE_DEPRECATIONS


GtkCssProvider *provider;
GtkStyleContext *context;

void change_color(GtkTextView *view, gpointer user_data)
{
    if (gtk_widget_has_focus(GTK_WIDGET(view)))
    {
        g_print("Focus \n");
        gtk_css_provider_load_from_data (provider,
                                 "textview text {"
                                 " font: 15px serif;"
                                 " color: green;"
                 " background-color:red;"
                                 "}",
                                -1);

        context = gtk_widget_get_style_context (GTK_WIDGET(view));
        gtk_style_context_add_provider (context,
                                GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER (provider),
                                GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
    }
    else
    {
        g_print("No Focus\n");
        gtk_css_provider_load_from_data (provider,
                                 "textview text {"
                                 " font: 15px serif;"
                                 " color: green;"
                                 "}",
                                -1);

        context = gtk_widget_get_style_context (GTK_WIDGET(view));
        gtk_style_context_add_provider (context,
                                GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER (provider),
                                GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
        }
}

void activate (GtkApplication *app, gpointer data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;

  window =gtk_application_window_new(app);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request(window,150,150);

  GtkWidget *view;
  GtkTextBuffer *buffer;

  view = gtk_text_view_new();

  g_signal_connect(view,"notify::has-focus",G_CALLBACK(change_color),NULL);

  buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (view));

  gtk_text_buffer_set_text (buffer, "Hello, this is some text", -1);

  provider = gtk_css_provider_new ();

  GtkWidget *box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL,5);
  GtkWidget *button = gtk_button_new_with_label("for demonstration only");
  gtk_box_append(GTK_BOX(box),button);
  gtk_box_append(GTK_BOX(box),view);
  gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(window),box);

  gtk_widget_set_visible(window,TRUE);
}


Greetings

This is how I did it in my app----
  PangoAttrList *attrlist = pango_attr_list_new();

  PangoAttribute *attrFC = pango_attr_foreground_new (65535, 0, 0); //red
  pango_attr_list_insert (attrlist, attrFC);

  PangoAttribute *attrBC = pango_attr_background_new (0, 0, 65535); //blue
  pango_attr_list_insert (attrlist, attrBC);

  /**set it on GtkText widget**/
  gtk_text_set_attributes ((GtkText *)text, attrlist);

  pango_attr_list_unref(attrlist);

Make the modifications as you need.

Thank you for taking the time to answer. Note that in your answer you use "GtkText" which has the requisite method; GtkTextView on the other hand doesn't.
